# Artificially increase one value and observe affects on another- Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-science, linear-regression

I have two columns where I would like to artificially increase column A value to 1000 to see what happens to values in column B.

**Data**

```
A           B
500         20
200         10
100         5
```

**Desired**

```
A           B
500        20
200        10
100        5
1000       ?
```

I wish to artificially increase column A value to 1000 to see what happens to values in column B.

**Doing**

Using python I will test for correlation.
Treat this as linear regression problem.

```
pyplot.scatter(x = ‘A’, y = ‘B’, s= 100)
pyplot.show()
```

Then I am thinking I can use linear regression to determine what the value of B will be if I increase the dependent value of A. Just not sure on how to input the what if A values.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.array([500,200,100]).reshape((-1, 1))
y = np.array([20,10,5])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create and fit a model before you can use it to make predictions.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x = np.array([500,200,100])
y = np.array([20,10,5])
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
reg.predict(np.array([1000]))
```

A graph might help. In this case, there is no strict linear relationship, but we are making a best guess. It's sort of like a computer drawing a line of best fit.

[image]

Here, the equation of the line of best fit would be `Y = 0.03654*X + 1.923`. Making a prediction just means plugging another X value into this formula to find the corresponding Y coordinate.

Comment: Ok What does the reg.predict [3,5] list signify?

Comment: Oh sorry I used the wrong numbers. I'll edit it quickly.

Comment: Ok we can only do if there is a relationship though right?

Comment: Well even if there isn't one, the linear regressor will try to find the closest matching linear relationship.

Comment: Ok will try - this sounds correct as I was thinking along the same train of thought

Comment: So the 1000 is just being appended to the A list?

Comment: No. The model `reg`  is being created from the two lists. That model contains the linear relationship between corresponding elements in the two lists. That model is then used to predict the corresponing result in the other list. It's sort of like a function machine mapping between the two lists, and the model is our best guess at what that function is. We then apply the function to what ever input you give to find the result (the element in the other list).

Comment: Ok thank you for explaining will try this

Comment: Oh the reshape.((-1,1) Is this just reshaping the dimension of the array?

Comment: Ok thank you for including the graph thank you

Comment: Oh, I just copied that part from your example, but I think that flips the array across the X axis, which for a 1 dimensional array would just be reversing it. That is probably not necessary.

Comment: Ok sure thank you - I’m familiar w Lin regression but didn’t know about the reg.predict(np.array([1000])) - this was really helpful- so this allows you to model a what if scenario. And if I wanted to input multiple variables, would I just do reg.predict(np.array([1000, 2000, 3000])) etc??